# Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined?

Tags: angular

```
search(event) {
  this.autocompletedata.forEach((entry) => {
    if (this.showFilter === '1') {
       this.results = entry['items'].filter(a => a['item'] ? a['item'].startsWith(event.query) : false);
    } else if (this.showFilter === '2') {
       this.results = entry['items'].filter(a => a['service'] ? a['service'].startsWith(event.query) : false);
    } else {
       this.results = entry['items'].filter(a => a['phoneNum'] ? a['phoneNum'].startsWith(event.query) : false);
    }
  });
}
```

I have a problem when i use startWith. Im getting this error:

> Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined

I have `array` inside `array`. So im `foreach` first  array and inside i find `array` of items. Inside `items` i have property `item`. Now im using autocomplete so when i enter test to get all data with test. Any suggestion what im doing wrong?

Comment: What it means in essence is that one or all of the items in `entry['items']` is undefined for the matching filter, either your `a['item']`, `a['service']` or `a['phoneNum']`? What might help is instead of calling `startsWith()` to print `entry['items']` and all the filtered items to the console first to debug that you actually receive the expected items to begin with.

Comment: @Fran That was my first thought, too. But he checks if the entry exists by using `a['item'] ? a['item'].startsWith()...`, so this error should never happen. At the end I would suggest mainly the same. Expand your lambda to a function body (use curly braces after the fat arrow) and add a `console.log()` (or `debugger;`) maybe surrounded by an if statement, depending how many entries you have to find the root cause.

Comment: thats it tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to expand your lambda function to have a proper body and debug your code (as @Oliver mentions) to find any possible data inconsistencies.

I can see another issue with your code though. In every iteration of your `forEach` you overwrite your `results` variable. This means that by the time the outer loop will have been finished, the `results` will contain only the last array the loop stumbles upon. The array can be empty, since your filter could have found nothing to put there. I'd suggest using the `map` function for such a transformation, or `flatMap` in case you no longer need an array of arrays in the end.

Something like this should work:

```
var data = [
    {items: [{item: 'a', service: 'a', phone: 'a'},{item: 'b', service: 'b', phone: 'b'}]}, 
    {items: [{item: 'a', service: 'a', phone: 'a'},{item: 'b', service: 'b', phone: 'b'}]}
];

var getFilter = prop => { return e => { return e[prop] && e[prop].startsWith(query) } };
var filters = { 1: getFilter('item'), 2: getFilter('service'), 3: getFilter('phone')};

var query = 'a', showFilters = 1;
var results = data.map(entry => { return entry['items'].filter(filters[showFilters]) });

console.log(results);

// flatMap is not on Array.prototype, you can define it yourself
Array.prototype.flatMap = f => { return this.map(f).reduce((x,y) => { return x.concat(y) }, []) };

results = data.flatMap(entry => { return entry['items'].filter(filters[showFilters]) });

console.log(results);
```